# Flask db migrat in Heroku didnt change database schema

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, heroku, sqlalchemy

Im trying to migrate my flask db using heroku. I performed the migrations in my local app, then committed the changes to github and deployed to heroku. I then executed
`heroku run flask db migrate` and `heroku run flask db upgrade` and based on the logs everything seems to have worked fine and without any errors:

```
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added column 'users.active'
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added column 'users.password'
  Generating /app/migrations/versions/a92ff10fdb60_.py ...  done

C:\Users\A>heroku run flask db upgrade -a certifit
Running flask db upgrade on ⬢ certifit... up, run.6994 (Free)
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl PostgresqlImpl.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume transactional DDL.
```

As seen from logs, the migration should have added two new columns to the users table:

```
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added column 'users.active'
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added column 'users.password'
```

However, when I run a SQL query the result is the same as prior migrataion:

```
 id |       email        | username |                                         password_hash                                         | acquirer_id
----+--------------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------
  4 | pooostgre@mail.com | fffff    | a3990046bdc7d7a861363eab41f5f4ac8a7f574fe314ea |          11
```

Any ideas what could be the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This article helped a lot https://gist.github.com/mayukh18/2223bc8fc152631205abd7cbf1efdd41/
In short:

1. Changed SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI from os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL') to heroku DATABASE_URL value (actual link). Im not sure if this made any difference during migrating database, but still I'll mention it here;
2. I ran flask db migrate and flask db upgrade in my local flask app.py (previously I did it in my heroku environment);
3. Changed SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL') (because of step 1);
4. Pushed changes to github and deployed new version to heroku